# Not able to extend an Objective-C class in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, fmdb, xcode8

I am using Swift 3.0 on Xcode 8.0 beta. I have installed a library using pods (FMDB) and now I am trying to extend one of its class in swift. I am able to use the API from my extended class but it crashes at runtime.

```
-[FMResultSet polygonsForColumnIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x608000056890
```

Below is the code for the extension:

```
public extension FMResultSet {

    public func polygons(forColumnIndex index: Int32) -> [NMAMapPolygon] {
```

It crashes here when called:

```
let rs = db.executeQuery("select AsGeoJSON(geometry) from COM262_Project", withArgumentsIn: nil)
        while (rs?.next())! {

            //Crashes here!
            let polygons = rs?.polygons(forColumnIndex: 0)    
        }
```

**Note**: Extensions work for other libraries like Alamofire.

Comment: What does the rest of the error say?

Comment: **-[FMResultSet polygonsForColumnIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x608000056890**

Comment: How do you call the method?

Comment: This kind of seems like a UI issue. Please double check your references for a missing/unused connection.

Comment: I defined an extension like you have above, and it works fine. I cannot reproduce your problem. The problem rests elsewhere. I know this is going to sound tiresome, but given that we can't reproduce this problem, I'd suggest you identify the precise steps required for this problem to manifest itself. E.g., create a blank project and add the minimal amount necessary to reproduce the problem. You can then share the precise steps necessary to reproduce the problem. But until we can reproduce the problem, it's hard to help you. BTW, I assume you're using Xcode 8 beta 6 (8S201h)?

Comment: Yes I am using Xcode 8 beta 6 (8S201h). Let me do it from scratch again and will let you know. Thanks for the reply. Appreciated!

Comment: Did you have any success?  Facing the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried setting the function as `@objc` e.g.

```
public extension FMResultSet {
    @objc public func polygons(forColumnIndex index: Int32) -> [NMAMapPolygon] {
```

On top of that have you changed the build setting `Enable Modules` to `Yes`.. Or if your using a config file `CLANG_ENABLE_MODULES = YES`

Comment: Tried this, but no success.